# Template does not exist: 500.html

Tags: django, django-templates

I have created a template for the 500 HTTP error.

I have inserted my template `500.html` in:

1. /project/
2. /project/templates/
3. /python2.5/
4. /python2.5/templates/

but I always get this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

I get the same problem for an HTTP 404 error.

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might need to specify the template directories in settings.py, if you haven't already.

e.g. in my settings.py, I have:

```
ROOTDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) 
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    ROOTDIR + '/logistics/templates',
)
```

Comment: First, try adding this to your template_dirs: C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin and see if that loads the default Django templates at all... And, if it does, then you're not specifying your dirs correctly. Note: my python instance and installed at C:\, change the path to whatever is right for your system.

Answer (score 5):

Try to set
`DEBUG=True` in your settings file

Comment: Definitely not on a production machine.

Comment: But on a devel machine it's quite useful. I couldn't remember why I didn't get debug messages anymore, so this hint is rather helpful. Thanks! :)

Comment: Normally this error occurs once setting up the installation the first time, by which you probably don't have lots of traffic. The standard error logging only helps you so much.

Comment: Debug True at least said something more to fix the bug, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your "Templates" configuration in your setting file like the below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Whl.png)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Hi @Abiola thanks for giving a look at this, but we believe how it would help is by providing relevant reference or sample.

Comment: @SuryaBhusal, see the updated solution above. "DIRS": is usually empty for new projects, so update it to properly point in the right folder for Django to find your templates.