# Django throws a 500 error

Tags: python, django, internal-server-error

Dear Python/Django expert,

Due to recent server migration, my python-powered django app throws a 500 page. The log file is listed below. Can you please give me some help in diagnosing this problem?

==========================

[haiyang@web aihaiyang]$ tail ~/logs/user/error_django_aihaiyang_log
[Fri Jun 29 17:25:57 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return callback(request, **param_dict), referer: http://aihaiyang.com/synlex/syntactic/

[Fri Jun 29 17:25:57 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/haiyang/webapps/django_aihaiyang/lib/python2.5/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view, referer: http://aihaiyang.com/synlex/syntactic/

[Fri Jun 29 17:25:57 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs), referer: http://aihaiyang.com/synlex/syntactic/

[Fri Jun 29 17:25:57 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/haiyang/webapps/django_aihaiyang/lib/python2.5/django/views/defaults.py", line 30, in server_error, referer: http://aihaiyang.com/synlex/syntactic/

[Fri Jun 29 17:25:57 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template., referer: http://aihaiyang.com/synlex/syntactic/

[Fri Jun 29 17:25:57 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/haiyang/webapps/django_aihaiyang/lib/python2.5/django/template/loader.py", line 157, in get_template, referer: http://aihaiyang.com/synlex/syntactic/

[Fri Jun 29 17:25:57 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     template, origin = find_template(template_name), referer: http://aihaiyang.com/synlex/syntactic/

[Fri Jun 29 17:25:57 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/haiyang/webapps/django_aihaiyang/lib/python2.5/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template, referer: http://aihaiyang.com/synlex/syntactic/

[Fri Jun 29 17:25:57 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name), referer: http://aihaiyang.com/synlex/syntactic/

[Fri Jun 29 17:25:57 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html, referer: http://aihaiyang.com/synlex/syntactic/

=========================

Thanks,
Haiyang

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template does not exist: 500.html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822422/template-does-not-exist-500-html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a 500.html template and put it in your template_dir
[Template does not exist: 500.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822422/template-does-not-exist-500-html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll create a 500.html and throw it there. But I'm just curious why it hit a 500 in the first place?

Comment: @aihaiyang when you are deploying django it requires you have a 500.html to show the user.