# Where in django is the default 500 traceback rendered so that I can use it to create my own logs?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-middleware, django-errors

I would like to use it to generate html log files inside the process_exception() method of my custom middleware class, e.g:

- Exception caught.
- process_exception(request) called.
- process_exception calls whatever function returns default error html.
- process_exception writes returned html to logs folder somewhere where django server is running.

I know that Django is capable of sending emails for these exceptions but i'd rather not use this. I'm working on a RESTful application using JSON and so it feels more appropriate to return a json string stating error 500 and then placing the html somewhere else.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry maybe I need to clarify: I don't want to create my own 500.html, I want to use the one that django uses when Debug=True. i.e. generate the error file and place it in a log folder.

***Thanks to Mark for the help - here is my solution for anyone interested:***

```
import logging
import os
import settings
import sys
import datetime

from response import get_json_response
from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter

logging.config.dictConfig(settings.LOGGING)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('console_logger')

class LoggingMiddleware(object):

    def process_exception(self,request,exception):
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        er = ExceptionReporter(request, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        file_path = os.path.join(settings.LOG_FOLDER, "{}.html".format(time))
        LOGGER.error("Writing error 500 traceback to %s" % file_path)
        file_handle = open(file_path,'w')
        file_handle.write(er.get_traceback_html())
        file_handle.close()
        return get_json_response(500,"HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error")
```

The code intercepts any exceptions, uses the sys module and djangos default error template to generate the nicely formatted traceback/exception info page and then places this in a log folder before returning a JSON object stating that there has been a http error 500.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 500 traceback page uses a template string (`TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE`) which is hard coded into `django.views.debug`. The report is generated by an `ExceptionReporter` class which is also included in `django.views.debug` which you should be able to re-purpose for your own log generation.

Answer (score 5):

If we want to show the exceptions that are generated in your template (`500.html`) then we could write your own 500 view, grabbing the exception and passing it to your 500 template.

### Steps:

### In my_app.views.py

```
import sys
import traceback

from django.http.response import HttpResponseServerError
from django.template import loader
from django.template.context import Context, RequestContext


def custom_500(request):
    t = loader.get_template('500.html')
    type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    return HttpResponseServerError(
        t.render(
            Context({
                'exception_value': value,
                'value': type,
                'tb': traceback.format_exception(type, value, tb)
            }, RequestContext(request))
        )
    )
```

### In Main Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
handler500 = 'my_app.views.custom_500'
```

### In Template (500.html)

```
{{ exception_value }}{{value}}{{tb}}
```

More about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate:
[Template does not exist: 500.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822422/template-does-not-exist-500-html)

Basically just put a 500.html in your template folder and it will use that.

Comment: Sorry maybe I need to clarify: I don't want to create my own 500.html, I want to use the one that django uses when Debug=True.

Comment: @Michael oh, sorry for misunderstanding and I'm glad someone else answered with the right answer.

Comment: No problem, I think my question could have been a lot clearer ;)