# Issue in deployment zc.buildout with apache

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, buildout

I am facing some issues with deploying my buildout project (Django) in Apache using mod_wsgi.

My folder structure:

```
t/
  bootstrap.py
  setup.py
  bin/
     buildout
     django
     django.wsgi
     .....
  eggs/
       raven-3.1.13-py2.7.egg
       ..........
  parts
  project
  develop-eggs
  src/
     some files
  myapp/

    files
    settings.py
    apicontainer/
        ....
```

Appache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/.../tests/website
         ServerName testapp.com
        <Directory /home/.../tests/website>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /website/ /home/.../tests/website/

        WSGIDaemonProcess testapp.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup testapp.com
        # ........ pointing to buildout's django.wsgi ..........
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/.../tests/t/bin/django.wsgi
        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn    
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

./bin/django.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
  '/home/.../tests/t/eggs/raven-3.1.13-py2.7.egg',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
   ...........
   ...........

  '/home/.../tests/t/eggs/djangorecipe-1.5-py2.7.egg',
  '/home/.../tests/t/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-2.0.0a3-py2.7.egg',
  '/home/.../tests/t',
  ]

import djangorecipe.wsgi

application = djangorecipe.wsgi.main('testproj.settings', logfile='')
```

buildout.cfg

```
[buildout]
parts = python
        django

develop = .
eggs = raven
       .....
       .....

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
wsgi = true
project = testproj
settings = settings
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

The apache error log I got is:

```
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=9772): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/.../tests/t/bin/django.wsgi'.
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return callback(request, **param_dict)
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 30, in server_error
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 157, in get_template
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
[Thu Feb 21 06:19:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

I give prmission(777) to bin folder.

To test wsgi work, I changed my django.wsgi as follows and I revert it back to old one.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

It gave me the result Hello World!.

Can you help me to find out the issues?

Comment: Does [Template does not exist: 500.html](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2822422) help at all? What does your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` look like?

Comment: At first I didn't give project = testproj in djangorecipe, Now I added it. Now am getting the 404page.ie  Its started working in some sort. Djano now looks for urls,setting, templates  in the generated directory for project. is this the default behivour?. It doesn't look in the src directory I created. Can I change this behivour?

Comment: what is the importance of 'project' in djangorecipe

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a TemplateDoesNotExist error which means you're missing a '500.html' template (see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view)).

I would suggest setting `DEBUG` to `True` in your `settings.py` file (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#debug)). That will cause django to use the built in debugging template (instead of the missing '500.html'). The debugging template will give you more information to work with...

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't used buildout, so I'm guessing a bit here. It sounds like a problem with your python path. Maybe try explicitly adding your app to extra_paths in your buildout.cfg.

Comment: DEBUG = True in my settings.py

Comment: now its working in some sort.Django looks for the urls specified in the generated project folder (specified in djangorecipe). Djngo doen't look my src folder for resources. How can I change it?