# <class 'django.template.base.TemplateDoesNotExist'>

Tags: python, django, deployment

I am deploying my django project, i set up the project on server and once i go to url, i end up seeing this error message.

since the error message is huge, i am adding screenshot here.

http://imagebin.org/279726

I created 500.html and 400.html.

this is my template settings in settings.py on prod server

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  "templates",
  os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates"),
)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What server are you using? How did you set it up? Is your Debug set to True or False? What are you expecting to see- the 500.html or some other template it is not finding?

Comment: How your project is deployed, what is variable PROJECT_PATH value? where are actual templates located?

Comment: While you might not realise that yet, I think here is [answer for your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822422/template-does-not-exist-500-html)

Comment: @yuvi, i am in debian7. i created virtualenv and inside that i installed django and other important packages and created django.fcgi and specified where the prod_settings.py is. now i saw in error log that prod_settings is not found and it says if it on sys.path.

Comment: @alko, thanks, i think, my prod_settings.py is not found, thats why it doesnot see template_dirs at all..

Comment: Try adding to your wsgi.py script two lines: `import sys` and then `sys.path.append('path/to/project')`. Do it before the os part that sets the environ for the settings. Did that change anything?

Comment: @yuvi, ok let me try this

Comment: @yuvi, yes, now it is using prod_settings but now i am getting error saying that it cannot find templates

Comment: Good. Now it's a matter of pointing it to the right place for the templates. Obviously, it cannot find one or more of the directories you are pointing to in TEMPLATE_DIRS. Can you share some more of your actual code?

Comment: @yuvi, sure. look at this image, i collected important information for you  http://imagebin.org/279734

Comment: That's weird. You say he is looking at the right directory. Are you 100% sure `/srv/home/dj574/data/public/wohne_env/templates/index.html` exists?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42258/discussion-between-doniyor-and-yuvi)

Comment: Also, your configuration of PROJECT_PATH actually points to the directory of settings.py (abspath doesn't actually do anything there). Try this instead: `PROJECT_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..'))`

Comment: HUGE PILES of thanks to Yuvi, it is working now